# Python- Scipy: if I have a 2D KDE from a distribution of data, can I then feed it a 1D array of "x" vals to get corresponding "y" vals?

Tags: python, kernel-density, scipy.stats

I have a simple 2D kernel density estimation created from x and y values, using scipy's gaussian_kde. It looks similar to the [example in the gaussian_kde documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html). I have new x values (a very simple 1D array) that need y values based on that initial distribution, is it even possible to get this out of gaussian_kde? Should I be using something else? Any advice is appreciated.

I have tried feeding that new 1D array into the kernel created by gaussian_kde, but of course it's expecting 2D data and I get a ValueError.

Comment: Are you interested in the conditional distribution of `y` given `x`, or something else?  (See the "Example" continuous distribution at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution.) If something else, please disambiguate "based on that initial distribution".